# ASPX c# attempt

Tags: asp.net, function, static-methods

This fun.aspx page gives me errors:
I want to code in APSX like as in PHP

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<html>
<body>
<%
int add1(int i) {
 return 1+i;
}
int x = 555;
try {
   Response.Write(add1(5));
    throw new Exception("error here1<br>\n");
} catch(Exception ex) {
    Response.Write("error detected");
}
%>
<h3>Lower</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "ASPX" and PHP have **VERY** different paradigms. You can treat ASP.Net like just a different language for doing PHP things if you really want to, but if you do you'll coming away thinking it sucks. The reality is, having used both, I strongly believe ASP.Net is a **much** better platform. But you need to learn to do things in it's way, and not PHP's broken way.

Comment: Also, "gives me errors" does not give us enough information to really help you. You _might_ get lucky and we'll be able to infer what's wrong from just reading the code, but actually telling us what the errors are, and what happened that was different from what you expected, will go a _long way_ towards making it possible for us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You still to use `runat=server`.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<script runat=server>
protected int add1(int i)
{
    return 1+i;
}
</script>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <% { Response.Write(add1(5)); } %>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Joel's comments are very helpful. To do things the ASP.NET way, you should take a look at the ASP.NET website [tutorials](https://www.asp.net/learn). Get to know just the basics of Web Forms and MVC because sooner or later you might have to opt for one over the other. I think at this stage, [MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc) would be a better time investment for you going forward as it will bring you to a closer understanding of HTTP and how the Web works.

With Web Forms, as with MVC, we should really aim to keep the code separate from the ASPX markup. Microsoft is pushing this in the Core version of MVC going forward with the use of MVC [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).

In the spirit of keeping presentation and functionality separate with Web Forms, you really should be using the code-behind file for the logic:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Label ID="totalLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**CS:**

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 555;
        totalLabel.Text = AddInteger(x);
    }

    protected int AddInteger(int i)
    {
        return 1+i;
    }
}
```